# Why does `document.createElement` do not allow the creation of self-closing tags?

Tags: javascript, dom, tags

Example JavaScript

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="test"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
let input_el = document.createElement('input');
input_el.setAttribute('type','text');
input_el.setAttribute('name','your_name');
let my_form = document.getElementById('test');
my_form.prepend(input_el);
```

Produces the following output in the chrome developer tools on windows (chrome version 96.0.4664.45):

[image]

And not the correct form:

```html
<input type="text" name="your_name">
```

Also see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m1fqzLv6/

For now I did not found any javascript function which would allow this.

Comment: *"Produces: `<input type="text" name="your_name"></input>`"* Where are you seeing / how are you getting that text output? Whatever it is, it's a facet of how that output is created, not what `createElement` does.

Comment: `createElement` doesn't create any **tags** at all. It creates **elements** (objects in memory). (Tags are the textual notation you use in markup to tell a parser to create elements.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `html_element.prepend(input_element)`

Comment: No, `prepend` isn't producing that output. It's just inserting the element in the DOM. Again: Where are you seeing / how are you getting that text?

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt: Your code is correct. You can also write it more concisely: `let input_del = document.createElement("input"); input.type = "text"; input.name = "your_name";` (since `type` and `name` are both reflected properties).

Comment: Your "tested on chrome browser" edit does not answer the question above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By running the code above (+ code lines to add the element to the dom with `prepend`) and looking at the developer tools how the element is rendered. So no, this is important to know cause browsers sometimes behave different.

Comment: So you're not generating any markup at all, you're talking about how the developer console displays the DOM objects.

Comment: That isn't how it's rendered in Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not true

Comment: What is `body` in the code?

Comment: FWIW, in Safari it's rendered as `<input ...>` in the DOM inspector, **but when you expand it, it gets an `</input>` to visualise where the expanded element ends.** Which is to say, you're not looking at HTML markup at all anyway, you're looking at a visual representation of a DOM, for which the developer tool chooses to use an HTML-like representation because, well, it makes sense. But you're still not looking at HTML generated by any Javascript.

Comment: 1. [Chrome dev tools Elements view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJtoo.png) 2. [Chrome dev tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXBEG.png) <== Notice that neither of them shows it that way. But **even it if did**, that would just be a quirk in how that tool displayed it for debugging. Again: No tags are created by `createElement`, and your code for creating the element is just fine. There is no issue to solve here. Your code is fine. Go forth and enjoy!

Comment: @deceze - That's....truly bizarre, given that `input` elements are `void` elements -- they can't have any content. So where they end isn't exactly unclear. :D

Comment: @T.J. Yeah, but you can expand it, and it has a shadow DOM. Must be some implementation detail.

Comment: @deceze - Makes sense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Again no! Look at the updated answer + jsfiddle! Maybe depends on OS and browser version!

Comment: @Sebi2020 - Interesting, and unfortunate, if they've started doing that in v96. As deceze said, perhaps it's to show the shadow DOM or some such. But please take a deep breath and re-read the comments above. As I said, *"But **even it if did**, that would just be a quirk in how that tool displayed it for debugging."* You're confusing the element tree with the *representation* of the element tree (its display, a textual form of it). There is no problem here (except a confusing choice by the devtools team, apparently). The `input` you're creating is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Sebi2020 - I just tried this on Chrome v96.0.4664.45 (Linux build) and I don't get `<input ...>...</input>`, just what I've shown in the screenshots above. https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2nqt.png (Created that using copy and paste with your code; I put the JavaScript in a `<script>...</script>` just before `</body>`.) I'm guessing you're doing more to that element than just creating and adding it? (Something which apparently changes how Chrome displays it.) I'd be keen to know what. Also: Is this an HTML doc, or XHTML doc? (Looks like HTML in the updated question.)

Comment: (FWIW re your deleted comment: [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tag) | [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Element). This is a common confusion lots of folks have.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The linked JSFiddle in my question exactly reproduces the output in the chrome developer tools (Windows, not Linux). The screenshot was taken from the jsfiddle page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's the shadow DOM. I've checked the shadow DOM option in the dev tools  and chrome seems to generate some shadow dom for input elements.

Comment: @Sebi2020 - Yup, that's it! (Confirmed at this end.) So like deceze was saying then. But you do understand now that this is just how devtools is showing it to you, right? :-) That's the key thing. Glad we figured out the devtools thing!

Comment: @Sebi2020 - Just for completeness, note that that option is for showing the *user agent's* shadow root (the browser's). You don't need that option to see your own shadow roots.

Answer (score 2):

This question is based on the assumption that `document.createElement()` would produce HTML code. This is incorrect.

Actually, the HTML code is parsed into a document object model (DOM). JavaScript can subsequently modify the DOM (also see comments from T.J. Crowder above). In your example, an `<input>` element is added.

Chrome, in its developer tool, represent the DOM by HTML code that most developers can easily read. And if there is an `<input>` element in the DOM, the devtools panel has to decide how to represent it. Apparently, it chooses the long form with `<input></input>`. This, however is only an output decision.